# Memory Error while append data frames in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am new to Python and Data Processing with pandas data frames. I would like to handle measurement data (*.mf4). This will read in, by using the package asammdf and create a pandas data frame.

My original attempt was to group the measurement data (single files) by the use of a dictionary. For post processing the data, I had always to loop through the dictionary to get the data frames. I found the `groupby` method and thought that might  work better than my dictionary attempt. At first, I limited the numbers of rows of the data frame up to 10, where it was working fine. Now running with full size of data (number of rows = 20000000) I got a memory error within the pandas data frame.

```
*new_values = new_values[argsort]
```

> MemoryError*

The output of `data_frame.info()` gives the following:

```
RangeIndex: 18410041 entries, 0 to 18410040
Data columns (total 12 columns):
dtypes: float64(8), int16(1), int32(1), int64(2)
memory usage: 1.5 GB
```

About 30 data_frames should be created and append to one.

```py
from asammdf import MDF
import pandas as pd

data_mi = pd.DataFrame()

for file in mf4_files:

 with MDF(file) as mdf_file:
 data_frame = mdf_file.to_dataframe(channels=labels)  # export mdf-data

 speed = int(config_data[file][0])  # speed
 load = config_data[file][1]  # load

 data_frame = data_frame.assign(load=load,speed=speed)
 data_frame.reset_index(inplace=True)

#data_mi = data_mi.append(data_frame.iloc[:10])
 data_mi = data_mi.append(data_frame) #select all data in one data frame


data_mi_max = data_mi.groupby(['load','speed'],sort=False).max()
```

Comment: It depends on the analysis you want to do. For example : if you'd only want to get the overall maximum of the 30 files, you could get the maximum for each file inside your for loop (and the overall max will be the max of those 30 maximums) so you won't have to store all 30 data files in memory.

Comment: Many thanks for your helb. For this case I could indeed do the postprocessing within the for loop. But still wonder what could I do, to minimize the amount of memory if I would append the data frames.

Comment: The single mf4-file got a size of about 400MB and the data frame needs 1.5 GB. And this despite the fact, that I only read a few columns of the measurement data. Would it be possible to work directly with the group objects . So doing something like this.`data_group = pd.concat([data_group, data_frame.groupby(['load', 'speed'])], axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the reduce_memory_usage argument? https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asammdf.mdf.MDF.to_dataframe

Comment: Many thanks for this advice. Did not know about the 'reduce_memory_usage'. I got a reduction of about half the original size. Have to check what the influence on the precision will be.